# How to position SVG with CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a button with an icon, cartcount and button text.
Now I already tried to make.

```css
.buttonCart {
  padding: 2px 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #28a8e0;
  height: 30px;
  /*float: right;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
}


.cartCornerIcon {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0;
  background-size: contain;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.cartCornerText {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="cartLinkClass" id="basketLinkId">
  <div class="buttonCart">
    <div class="cartCornerIcon">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 1.09448819 900.3622047">
        <path d="M112.58 327.79v-32h90.468l112.015 256h245.5v32H294.126l-112.016-256M400.563 663.79c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48s-48-21.5-48-48 21.5-48 48-48 48 21.5 48 48zM560.563 663.79c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48s-48-21.5-48-48 21.5-48 48-48 48 21.5 48 48z" />
      </svg>
      <div id="itemCountForCart">
        0
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cartCornerText">
      Bestellen
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

But what I actually want is this:

[image]

Anyone here who can help and maybe also can give some tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `position:absolute` in your `SVG` and some `text-indent` in your `#itemCountForCart`

```css
.buttonCart {
  padding: 2px 40px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #28a8e0;
  height: 30px;
  /*float: right; - removed for demo */
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
/*cart in corner top start*/

.cartCornerIcon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cartCornerText {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top:8px
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  left: -42px;
  top: -8px;
}
#itemCountForCart {
  text-indent:-.8em
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="cartLinkClass" id="basketLinkId">
  <div class="buttonCart">
    <div class="cartCornerIcon">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1.09448819 900.3622047">
        <path d="M112.58 327.79v-32h90.468l112.015 256h245.5v32H294.126l-112.016-256M400.563 663.79c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48s-48-21.5-48-48 21.5-48 48-48 48 21.5 48 48zM560.563 663.79c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48s-48-21.5-48-48 21.5-48 48-48 48 21.5 48 48z" />
      </svg>
      <div id="itemCountForCart">
        0
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cartCornerText">
      Bestellen
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little less complex way of doing this:

```css
body {
  margin: 50px 20px; /* Only for showing it under the snipper 'fullscreen' button */
}

a {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #28a8e0;
  float:right;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a span {
  line-height: 14px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;    
}

a span.svg {
  position: relative; 
}

a span.counter {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 left: 23px;
 top: 7px;
}

a span svg {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <span class="svg">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 1.09448819 900.3622047"><path d="M112.58 327.79v-32h90.468l112.015 256h245.5v32H294.126l-112.016-256M400.563 663.79c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48s-48-21.5-48-48 21.5-48 48-48 48 21.5 48 48zM560.563 663.79c0 26.5-21.5 48-48 48s-48-21.5-48-48 21.5-48 48-48 48 21.5 48 48z"/>           </svg>
    <span class="counter">0</span>
  </span>
  <span>Bestsellen</span>
</a>
```

You can of course fiddle with it (css) to get it to look exactly the way you want it. Please note that you should correct your svgs viewbox for it to be displayed nicely in the center.